# System Threading Error using Kii Authentication with Unity WebGL

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl, kiicloud

I'm creating a WebGL application using Unity written in C#.

I have a function that logs the user in based on an authentication token (allowing the user to skip the login screen if they've signed in previously and have a cookie).

The application works flawlessly in the Unity environment when I hit the play button. However, when I build the application and run it locally in my browser I get a "System.SystemException: Thread creation failed." error in my console log. This error seems to occur right after the user is logged in. My login function is:

```
public void loginWithAccessIDToken(string accessIDToken, Action<KiiUser> success)
    {  
        //Use the access token to sign-in again
        try
        {
            Debug.Log("About to log in...");

            KiiUser.LoginWithToken(accessIDToken, (KiiUser user, Exception e) =>
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Got Something!");
                if (e != null)
                {
                    User = null;
                    success(User);
                    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Exception caught...");
                }
                else
                {
                    User = user;
                    success(User);
                    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Login successful...");
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Log("Exception caught..." + e.Message);
            success(User);
        }
    }
```

I have also attached a screenshot of the error I receive in Firefox below. It seems to me that Kii is doing some sort of threading. I've read online that WebGL does not support threading.. however, I do not have a good understanding of what Kii is attempting to do!

Does anyone have experience implementing this logic in their application? I'm able to keep my application running if I have exceptions enabled in the Unity build settings. Although, this is surely not a permanent solution!

If anyone has any suggestions or would like more information about my build settings please ask.

[FireFox Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6SEF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The System.Threading namespace is unavailable in WebGL at the moment. Unfortunately, it sounds like this problem lies within a third party library.

To support WebGL you can use coroutines instead of threads, but it sounds like you would have to contact the developers of Kii.

Comment: You're likely correct. I also posted this question on the Kii Community Boards and someone posted saying the Kii SDK Is not supported in WebGL. It's too bad their documentation is not clearer that their SDK only works for Unity's Web Player.